# Login Multiusuario y contraseña en Python: Problemas con el condicional

Tags: python, login, contraseña, cuenta-usuario

Buenas Tardes a Todos:

Estoy intentando hacer un login de cuatro usuarios cada uno con su respectiva contraseña de la siguiente manera

```
Usuario  Contraseña 
-------- ------------
Paula    1234
Jorge    6678
Maria    0066
Jairo    1020
Laura    1111
```

Para lo cual empecé con una lista con los usuarios y otra con las claves, luego agregue un for que recorriera la lista usuarios y otro para las claves, así:

```
Usuarios = ["Paula","Jorge","Maria","Jairo","Laura"]**

Claves = ['1234','6678','0066','1020','1111']** 

Usuario = input('Escriba el usuario: ')

Pasa = input('Ingrese la Contraseña: ')

for Usuario in Usuarios:
    for Pasa in Claves:
        if Usuario == Usuarios & Pasa == Claves:
            print('El usuario y clave son corretos')
        else:
            print('Alguno de los datos es incorrecto')
```

Por el momento me deja ingresar el usuario y la contraseña, pero me aparece este error

```
-> 9  if Usuario == Usuarios & Pasa == Claves:
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'str'
```

Tambien lo intenté a modo de diccionario, pero me sigue saliendo el error:

```
Usuarios = {'Paula':'1234', 'Jorge':'6678', 'Maria':'0066', 'Jairo':'1020', 'Laura':'1111'}
Nombre = input('Escriba el usuario: ')
Clave = input('Ingrese la Contraseña: ')

for Usuario in Usuarios:
    if Nombre == Usuario & Clave == Usuarios[Usuario]: 
        print('El usuario y clave son corretos')
    else:
            print('Alguno de los datos es incorrecto')
```

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia se les agradece mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes los siguientes errores en el código:

- Utilizas el operador & (intersección), cuando quieres utilizar el operador booleano `and`
- Utilizas las mismas variables para pedir los datos al usuario y luego para recorrer la o las listas, con lo que estás perdiendo los datos ingresados por el usuario.
- En cada iteración del ciclo imprimes el mensaje `Alguno de los datos es incorrecto`, y esto es incorrecto, en realidad quieres imprimir el mensaje solo luego de terminar de asegurarte que el usuario no existe.

Dentro de los enfoques que tienes, me parece más correcto el del diccionario, por más simple, pero la manera de accesarlo es errónea ya que no hace falta recorrer todos los elementos del mismo, sino que, con el método `get()`, puedes determinar si existe el elemento del usuario ingresado e ir directamente a este para comparar la clave, por ejemplo:

```
usuarios = {'Paula':'1234', 'Jorge':'6678', 'Maria':'0066', 'Jairo':'1020', 'Laura':'1111'}
nombre = input('Escriba el usuario: ')
clave = input('Ingrese la Contraseña: ')

if (usuarios.get(nombre)) and (usuarios[nombre]==clave):
    print("¡Todo OK!")
else:
    print("¡Algún dato es incorrecto!")
```

No es que no pueda hacerse con las dos listas, pero en este caso no hace falta anidar el recorrido de ambas listas, pues una sola contraseña pertenece a cada usuario. En realidad tienes que hacer un ciclo que te permita acceder a los valores de ambas listas por su posición, para encontrar una coincidencia. Como ya he dicho antes, en este caso, el recorrido lo usamos para *detectar* si hay una coincidencia y el mensaje lo imprimimos al final. Para conseguirlo en el ejemplo, me auxilio de una variable booleana llamada `encontrado` y voy recorriendo los elementos por su índice con la variable `idx`:

```
usuarios = ["Paula","Jorge","Maria","Jairo","Laura"]
claves = ['1234','6678','0066','1020','1111']

nombre = input('Escriba el usuario: ')
clave = input('Ingrese la Contraseña: ')

encontrado = False
for idx in range(len(usuarios)):
    if (nombre == usuarios[idx]) and (clave == claves[idx]):
        encontrado = True
        break

if (encontrado):
    print("¡Todo OK!")
else:
    print("¡Algún dato es incorrecto!")
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Mi hermano, el codigo funciono perfecto, se te agradece el aporte, ya lo tengo mas claro y aprendo un poco mas cada vez, exitos a ti.

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera [marcar la respuesta como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y, si es de buena calidad, votar a favor. Es la forma, en StackOverflow, de _agradecer_ a quien responde y de ayudar a navegantes futuros a identificar que la respuesta fue de ayuda.Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta o como votar por ella, repite el [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Para el condicional "y" se utiliza "and", "&&" se utiliza en lenguajes como c,c++,etc.
Por lo que veo ese seria el problema, lo demas esta bien, tanto usando listas o diccionarios esta bien hecho, pero por buenas practicas para usuario-contraseña recomiendo diccionarios.

Comment: Fabian que tal, Efectivamente cambie la & por el and ya reconocio corre perfecto, aunque muestra  el mensaje del condicional tantas veces como elementos del diccionario; Muchas Gracias hombre

Answer (score 1):

Como @jachguate ya te ha dicho los errores que tienes, solo modificaré ligeramente sus códigos para proponerte otra solución:

Con listas:

```
usuarios = ["Paula","Jorge","Maria","Jairo","Laura"]
claves = ['1234','6678','0066','1020','1111']

usuario_clave = zip(usuarios, claves)

nombre = input('Escriba el usuario: ')
clave = input('Ingrese la Contraseña: ')

if (nombre, clave) in usuario_clave:
    print("¡Todo OK!")
else:
    print("¡Algún dato es incorrecto!")
```

Con `zip` obtendrías tuplas: `('Paula', '1234') ('Jorge', '6678')...` y con if `(nombre, clave) in usuario_clave` compruebas que coincidan.

Con un diccionario:

Coincido con que esta opción es mejor, pero puedes sustituir la parte en la que compruebas poniendo:

```
usuarios = {'Paula':'1234', 'Jorge':'6678', 'Maria':'0066', 'Jairo':'1020', 'Laura':'1111'}
nombre = input('Escriba el usuario: ')
clave = input('Ingrese la Contraseña: ')

if usuarios[nombre] == clave:  # Esta línea puede modificarse así
    print("¡Todo OK!")
else:
    print("¡Algún dato es incorrecto!")
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias tambien a ti hermano, me sirve de mucha ayuda; Exitos.